# Faster way to find matching patterns from external file grep -f {patternfile} {source} in BASH

Tags: bash, grep

In *nix terminal (Bash) os there any other faster way to find a pattern (or excluding them - egrep -v option) than using this:

```
grep -f {patternfile} {source}
```

Using this option is painfully slow for larger files.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams not quite, you can match them in O(N + M), N the file length, M the sum of all pattern lengths

Comment: Try `LC_ALL=C grep -f patternfile source` if applicable

Comment: What's a `bash` tool?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - a tool for bashing stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your patterns are fixed strings, have a look at [agrep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrep) ([download](ftp://ftp.cs.arizona.edu/agrep/)) (or other matchers that are based on the Wu-Manber algorithm).  It will match all patterns in parallel.

Wu-Manber is generally good for up to a few hundred thousand patterns (maybe a million at a push).

For regular expressions I think there's no generally fast approach.

Comment: Unfortunately agrep does not support reading patterns from file and for my arguments list is too long. "/usr/bin/agrep: Argument list too long"

Comment: Oh, didn't know that, I couldn't use agrep either.  I've implemented the Wu-Manber myself because I needed a twist though: matching ~200k - 900k patterns against 10+ million files, only report matches ... don't suppose that's of any use?

Comment: Um, agrep (from ftp://ftp.cs.arizona.edu/agrep/) *does* support patterns from a file, btw, it's `-f`

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what type of file you're searching through but another tool that I've seen used for searching which might give you better performance is [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/).

It doesn't however provide the ability to search using a pattern file. However you can use this approach to coax `ack` into searching for multiple patterns like so:

```
  $ grep -Ffx <(ack -l "pattern1" file) <(ack -l "pattern2" file)
```

This could easily be put into a Bash script making it more general purpose.